# Why reputation decreased by 1 on down-vote?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

Lately I noticed, when I downvote a answer(Which according to me is poor) my reputation is reduced by 1. 
Is this a standard procedure or something wrong with my downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

Downvotes on questions don't give -1, to promote well researched questions which are not easily found elsewhere in the net.
Downvotes on answers imply a small negative effect, so that you value them well. It is much smaller than the amount you get when you are upvoted, so it shouldn't pose a problem.

This was slightly different in the past, the current situation was explained some months ago by SE staff.
So, the observed behaviour is normal.

Ps: You can also flag for attention problematic answers or questions, and it doesn't affect your rep.

Comment: that's fine. Just asked to get clarified whether am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Just attribute to downvotes and reputation the right meaning and proceed to filter out the best and the worst contributions. Btw you can also suggest edit to improve clarity or quality.

Comment: FWIW, it _used_ to be that downvotes on questions had a cost too, but apparently the decision was that questions weren't getting enough downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the key reasons Stack Exchange *works*. On Facebook Questions, for example, everyone voted down all competing answers, basically making the thing useless. There are other ways to solve that, but this is very elegant.

By the time you have enough reputation to go on a downvoting rampage, you're usually engaged enough with the site that you *won't*.

Comment: @ mattdm ya.. Got it..